# What happens to amortized analysis in binary counter if flipping a bit at index k costs now 2^k instead of 1?

Tags: algorithm, amortized-analysis

Suppose that flipping bit #*i* costs 2<sup>*i*</sup>; so, flipping bit #0 costs 1, flipping bit #1 costs 2, flipping bit #2 costs 4, and so on.

What is the amortized cost of a call to `Increment()`, if we call it *n* times?

I think the cost for *n* Increments should be *n*·2<sup>0</sup>/2<sup>0</sup> + *n*·2<sup>1</sup>/2<sup>1</sup> + *n*·2<sup>2</sup>/2<sup>2</sup> + … +*n*·2<sup>*n*−1</sup>/2<sup>*n*−1</sup> = *n*(*n*−1) = *O*(*n*<sup>2</sup>). So each Increment should be *O*(*n*), right? But the assignment requires me to prove that it's *O*(log *n*). What have I done wrong here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59220703/amortized-cost-of-modified-increment-function/59222609#59222609

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let we have p-bit integer and walk through all `2^p` possible values.

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 1 0 
0 1 1
1 0 0 
1 0 1 
1 1 0
1 1 1
```

The rightmost bit is flipped `2^p` times (at every step), so overall cost is `2^p`
The second bit is flipped `2^(p-1)` times but with cost 2, so we have overall cost `2^p`
..
The most significant bit is flipped once, but with cost `2^p`, so we   have overall cost `2^p`

Summing costs for all bits, we have full cost `p*2^p` for all operations.

Per-operation (amortized) cost is `p*2^p / 2^p = p`

But note this is cost in bit quantity, and we must express it in `N` terms

```
N = 2^p 
 so 
p = log(N)
```

Finally amortized complexity per operation is `O(log(N))`